# CSRF JS Metatag Creation w/ Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf, csrf

I am going out on a limb as I'm not certain this is even possible but I was looking to create two CSRF meta-tags (header and token) within a javascript file which is used through out the site.  However, I don't believe it is possible because of how thyme leaf processes data from interpolated data variables.

I have tried creating the HTML meta tag element with the following code:

```
var meta = document.createElement("meta");
meta.setAttribute("name", "_csrf");
meta.setAttribute("th:content", "_csrf.token")
```

This creates the necessary element--token only shown--with the desired values.  However, when printing out the values for the token it returns "_csrf.token" rather than the actual csrf value.  I believe it's because thymeleaf is not processing interpolating the values correctly.

Must these meta-tags be added to each page's html files manually  or can they be created dynamically using a common javascript file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using layout:dialect to create a template that all your pages have access too.  You can put the `<meta />` tag there and share it between all your pages.

If you're set on using JavaScript, you can run JavaScript through the same spring process as your pages (if you have everything set up correctly for it).  For example, something like this:

```java
@GetMapping("/your-javascript-name.js")
public String deposit() {
    return "javscript/your-javascript-name";
}
```

That way you can still include it externally:

```html
<script src="your-javascript-name.js"></script>
```

And in the javascript, you can use Thymeleaf:

```js
var token = /*[[${_csrf.token}]]*/ '';

var meta = document.createElement("meta");
meta.setAttribute("name", "_csrf");
meta.setAttribute("content", token);
```